# why is my desktop appear so pixelated

Tags: windows-10, display, desktop

I just setup my brand new PC installed all the drivers.

but the desktop font looks really weird. and I am not sure if this is Windows issue or Monitor issue or Graphics Card issue.

I googled some similar topics, and I did driver updates, and tried different custom scaling but none of them works.

Any suggestions?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Looks perfectly normal in your screenshot

Comment: I don't see anything strange.

Comment: If you go into Display settings do you have your zoom view set higher then 100%? Because sometimes things become pixelated when you change enlarge windows.

Comment: Just saw the image. Try setting the Zoom to 100%

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your personalized setting try setting the display zooming to 100% by:

> **Right Click on Desktop Settings -> Display -> text, apps, and other items: `100%`**.

Then Logoff you account and Login and see if the text becomes less blurry.

[image: Image of display settings - Customize your display - Change the size of text, apps, and other items: 100%]

Comment: I had same issue